# Datable.Select sort expression

Tags: c#, datatable.select

I have datatable with column name tag and 100 rows of data.I need to filter this table with tag starting with "UNKNOWN".

What should my sortexpression for datatable.select be ?

I'm trying the following.

```
Datarow[] abc = null;
abc = dtTagList.Select(string.format("tag='{0}'","UNKNOWN"))
```

How can I achieve tag startswith 'UNKNOWN' in the above code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("tag like 'UNKNOWN%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously you don't need to pass in a *sort* expression - you want a *filter* expression.

According to the MSDN article on [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx), the expression you pass in obeys the same rules as the [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) property, which supports the LIKE operator.

So give this a whirl:

```
abc = dtTagList.Select("tag LIKE 'UNKNOWN%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dtTagList.Select(string.format("tag LIKE '{0}'","UNKNOWN%"))
```